# I'd like to search a .csv file and return all rows containing a value within a range

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file which looks a little like:

```
ID, Start, End
1, 1, 20,
2, 25, 40,
3, 67, 100
```

The main function of my code then prompts the user to choose some options (I've only shown the one I'm interested in here):

```
def Main():

    response = input('1, 2 or 3? ')

    if response == 2:
        Begin = raw_input('Start coordinate: ')
        End = raw_input('End coordinate: ')
        Return_all(Begin, End)
```

As you can see, the main then calls a function depending on the users choice.. With this particular function I'd like to print the 'ID' value from all rows where the start and end values are within

```
def Return_all(start, end):
    file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('csv_file.csv'))
    Start = int(start)
    End = int(end)
    for row in file_csv:
        if row['Start'] == range(Start, End):
            print row['ID']
```

Ultimately, given a start and end coordinate of say 1 and 45, respectively, I'd like this program to then print IDs 1 and two to the console. Given coordinates of 25 and 200, I'd like it to only print IDs 2 and 3, and so on.

However, this doesn't seem to work quite as expected, although I don't get any errors, I also don't see anything printed to the console. Is anyone able to suggest a better option for achieving what I need?

Cheers

Comment: `if Start <= row['Start'] <= End:`, although your variable names are a little confused, that is a good way to check a range of values,

Comment: @martineau Thanks for pointing out a slightly more conservative way of using ranges. However, my script still does not print the IDs

Comment: If you want to check if both the `'Start'` and `'End'` row values are in the range, then the statement would have to be `if (Start <= row['Start'] <= End) and (Start <= row['End'] <= End):`. Your choice of argument and local variable names that are the same as keys in the row dictionaries makes the code very confusing. The fact that you're also ignoring the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

When using the `csv` module, all entries are treated as strings, so you need to first convert the values to ints as follows:

```
import csv

def Return_all(start, end):
    with open('csv_file.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)

        for row in csv_input:
            csv_start = int(row['Start'])

            if start <= csv_start <= end:
                print row['ID']

Return_all(1, 45)           
print
Return_all(25, 200)
```

This would display:

```
1
2

2
3
```